# PayPal Adaptive payments' sandbox page not found

Tags: api, paypal, http-status-code-404, sandbox

I have been using my API class for months without any problems however suddenly the sandbox page stopped working.

The payment link which I am trying to access is: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=AP-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX , however I am getting 404 error on the page.

> HTTP Status 404 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The requested resource () is not available.

Have they made any modifications to the link structure after the recent update? I have done my research but couldn't find anything, any guidance is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has the error persisted? Visiting the -XXXX link, I get "This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website and try again."

Comment: No, I just tried again and it is working fine. It wasn't working a hour ago.